# Pass variables form PHP to bash in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, bash, laravel-5

I've a function in controller in which I'm trying to pass a variable form PHP to bash in SSH facade.

```
putenv("UNIQKEY=test123");
SSH::into('production')->run([
                     "if [ -d 'public_html' ]; then
                          cd public_html/
                          touch laber.txt
                          key=$UNIQKEY
                          echo key >> laber.txt
                      fi"
]);
```

Here I'm trying to write a key to the text file. When I write what I'm getting is key inside the file. not the expected test123.
What am I doinf wrong...

Comment: Where does `$1` come from?

Comment: @edhurtig I've updated the question. It is the variable UNIQKEY inside putenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `echo key` to `echo \$key`, otherwise the shell is not going to expand out the key variable.

Additionally, you can get rid of the key variable altogether and avoid some nasty shell escaping by just using `$UNIQKEY`

There is the other problem where you are using putenv and expecting the environment variable to carry through the SSH connection.  I do not believe env vars are transferred like this.  Instead, simply set a PHP variable for $UNIQKEY and interpolate it in your shell script.

```
$UNIQKEY='test123';
SSH::into('production')->run([
                     "if [ -d 'public_html' ]; then
                          cd public_html/
                          touch laber.txt
                          echo $UNIQKEY >> laber.txt
                      fi"
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `$UNIQKEY`, escape the $ to `\$UNIQKEY` .